# Value only changes once, why is that

Tags: javascript

The priceCur needs to update to a new value every time a random num is generated at 9 or 10.
This seems not to be happening, and I don't see why.

```
var companyOne = {
    industry:"tech",
    cName:"",
    totalShares:100000,
    priceStart:10,
    priceCur:10
};

var randomGenerated = Math.floor((Math.random() * 11) + 0); // 0 - 10
console.log(randomGenerated);

if(randomGenerated >= 9){
    companyOne.priceCur = companyOne.priceCur * (1 + 0.050); //5% increase
    console.log('current_share', companyOne.priceCur)

}
```

Comment: You are only changing it once.

Comment: Just noticed. I'm tired, should have spotted that though. Got it in a function now to run every few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it only runs once, because you are only assigning and logging a value once. In order for it to change multiple times, you'll need to add a conditional statement or an event listener etc so that it runs multiple times. Here is an example (an infinite loop):

```
while (true) {

    var companyOne = {
        industry:"tech",
        cName:"",
        totalShares:100000,
        priceStart:10,
        priceCur:10
    };

    var randomGenerated = Math.floor((Math.random() * 11) + 0); // 0 - 10
    console.log(randomGenerated);

    if(randomGenerated >= 9) {
        companyOne.priceCur = companyOne.priceCur * (1 + 0.050); //5% increase
        console.log('current_share', companyOne.priceCur)

    }

}
```